# How to create common style with guidelines ConstraintLayout?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have 10 xml files with common code for setting guidelines:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline_top"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.15" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline_bottom"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.97" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline_left"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.95" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline_right"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.05" />
```

I don't understand how to create some common style which will be set for all these files without usage of common code? I saw that I can use constraints in style, but how I can call guideline in style?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve my problem with `<merge ...>` in layouts ([docs](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts)). I created file with my views:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline_top"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.15" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline_bottom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.97" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline_left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.95" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline_right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.05" />

</merge>
```

and I can add it to my target screen by this line:

```
<include layout="@layout/guidelines" />
```